# angular2 Universal for backend get hostname

Tags: angular, universal

client

```
this._service.get('/api/user').subscribe(user => {

})
```

server

```
app.use('/api/user', function(req){
    console.log(req.hostname)  //always get localhost  

})
```

If my check isBrowser no problem ， can get hostname

```
if( isBrowser )
{
    this._service.get('/api/user').subscribe(user => {
        this.store.dispatch({ type: SETUSER, payload: user })
    })
}
```

How to render in the backend Get the hostname

Comment: what you want to get? localhost along with port number? add your expected value along with the value which you are currently getting.

Comment: I get localhost .  I want get domain  (*.com )

Answer (score 1):

fix server.ts

```
function ngApp(req, res) 
{
    res.render('index', 
    {
        req,
        res,
        preboot: false,
        baseUrl: '/',
        hostname: req.hostname,
        requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
        originUrl: `http://${req.hostname}:${ app.get('port') }`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the host name along with the protocol and other details use tye below code

```
app.use('/api/user', function(req){
    console.log(req.hostname)  //always get localhost  
    console.log(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host);
    //output of the above line will be (https://stackoverflow.com)
})
```